# Coloring statistically significant bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Usually in publications, statistically significant differences are shown by putting * above the bar. I have a lot of bars in my plot and I was hoping to make significant ones different from the others by coloring it differently.

For example:
this is the dataset

```
some_data = data.frame(name = sample(LETTERS, 5), 
                       value = rnorm(5, 5, 7), 
                       pvalue = rnorm(5, 0.05, 0.02))

> some_data
  name      value     pvalue
1    Q  8.8101784 0.01691628
2    Z  5.9426036 0.10228445
3    U  1.4862314 0.02062453
4    K -0.1365665 0.04405621
5    N  8.8828848 0.05992229

ggplot(some_data, aes(name, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=pvalue), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

What I want is to make the bars different colored if pvalue was more less than 0.05

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` aesthetics let you evaluate R code, which allows you to do stuff like this:

```
ggplot(some_data, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = pvalue < 0.05)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=pvalue), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

EDIT: Use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` per Axeman's comment.

Comment: Also note that `geom_col` has superseded the `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` idiom.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know these.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark under the answer's voting arrows.